# Jasig CAS implementation in .NET

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, single-sign-on, cas, jasig

I am using webforms on .net 4.0 and am really struggling to get this to work. I have used the documentation from the jasig site – and installed the nuget package for the client.

https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASC/.Net+Cas+Client

I'm logging in sucessfully and am getting a token back from the CAS server, but cannot seem to authenticate it. As far as I can see there are three different service methods to call to validate the token:

/validate

/serviceValidate

/samlValidate

The validate method simply returns a web response of “no” while when I call the serverValidate method it returns a code of INVALID_TICKET in the XML response. I have tried also the samlValidate but receive a 403 error (I understand that this is a potentially valid response).

My validate code is something like this:

```
 var validateurl = APPLICATION + "validate?" +
                    "ticket=" + tkt + "&" +
                    "service=" + service;


  StreamReader Reader = new StreamReader(new WebClient().OpenRead(validateurl));
  string resp = Reader.ReadToEnd();
```

My CAS config is:

```
<casClientConfig casServerLoginUrl="https://*IPSERVER*/cas/login"
                   casServerUrlPrefix="https://*IPSERVER*/cas/"
                   serverName="http://*MYSITE*/"
            notAuthorizedUrl="~/NotAuthorized.aspx"
                   cookiesRequiredUrl="~/CookiesRequired.aspx"
                   redirectAfterValidation="true" gateway="false" renew="false" singleSignOut="true"
                   ticketTimeTolerance="5000" ticketValidatorName="Cas20" proxyTicketManager="CacheProxyTicketManager"
           serviceTicketManager="CacheServiceTicketManager"
           gatewayStatusCookieName="CasGatewayStatus" />
```

I figure it must be a setting of some sort, but for the life of me I cannot work out what the setting might be.

Can anyone tell me why I cannot validate the token?

**Edit:**
Having thought about this a little more, I'm even more confused. If as @Steven V below says, the client app cookie is created by the httpmodule - how does any page get authenticated? For example if I am in my client (RP) app page (landing.aspx, say) and click a link to the (IP) authentication server to restricted content (restricted.aspx, say) - how does the server magically create a cookie on the client before it redirects to restricted.aspx after logging me in. Using WIF I'd still have to do a `FormsAuthentication.CreateAuthCookie()` or similar in code.

What is happening if I click on the link to my restricted page, is that I am redirected to the (IP) CAS server pages as expected, and after sucessful login get an infinite redirect, because presumably the app does not have a local client cookie and tries to authenticate, so redirects to the server which has already authenticated and redirects back to the client, which does not have a local cookie, so needs to authenticate.. forever.

**Edit again:** I have read further on this (there is not much available out there) and found that this authentication happens at a very low level and is supposed to happen on the client app (RP) setting the cookie before the page redirect. This clearly is not happening for me, and I have no clue as to how to go about working out what is going wrong.

Comment: Why are you trying to validate the ticket manually? In our CAS implementation(s), the ticket validation is taken care of by the HttpModule, then sets the Identity correctly.

Comment: Because when I tried to do this, I logged in successfully via the IP, but never made it back to the restricted content of my site. At what stage do you log in locally?

Comment: .. and how do you set the local user cookie for that matter?

Comment: We have applications that protect a piece of an application, and the full application. We use the web.config `<authorization>` element to achieve that. The user cookie is set by Jasig automatically, and no implementation is required beyond editing the web.config. Take a look at Jasig's sample .NET application at https://github.com/Jasig/dotnet-cas-client/tree/master/ExampleWebSite.

Comment: Unfortunately I have tried this, and get the same behavior as on my test project. I suspect there are some custom settings on the server that might be behind this. As I have not control over the server - and have little communication with those that run it - I don't fancy my chances of resolving this issue easily

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up having to download the source for the Jasig CAS client and implement a new ticket validator. The IP that we are using is ECAS, the European Commission's Authentication Service, and it did not support my client's permission level.

For anyone interested, or anyone who happens to be trying to connect to ECAS (.NET is not one of their supported platforms). From the .NET client in the /Validation/Schema/TicketValidator folder, you can implement something like:

```
namespace DotNetCasClient.Validation.TicketValidator
{
    internal class ECasServiceTicketValidator : Cas20ServiceTicketValidator
    {
```

In the CasAuthentication.cs file you need to add these snippets:

```
        // Names for the supported ticket validators
        public const string CAS10_TICKET_VALIDATOR_NAME = "Cas10";
        public const string CAS20_TICKET_VALIDATOR_NAME = "Cas20";
        public const string ECAS_TICKET_VALIDATOR_NAME = "ECas";
        public const string SAML11_TICKET_VALIDATOR_NAME = "Saml11";
```

And

```
if (String.Compare(ticketValidatorName, CasClientConfiguration.CAS10_TICKET_VALIDATOR_NAME, true) == 0)
                        {
                            ticketValidator = new Cas10TicketValidator();
                        }
                        else if (String.Compare(ticketValidatorName, CasClientConfiguration.CAS20_TICKET_VALIDATOR_NAME, true) == 0)
                        {
                            ticketValidator = new Cas20ServiceTicketValidator();
                        }
                        else if (String.Compare(ticketValidatorName, CasClientConfiguration.ECAS_TICKET_VALIDATOR_NAME, true) == 0)
                        {
                            ticketValidator = new ECasServiceTicketValidator();
                        } 
                        else if (String.Compare(ticketValidatorName, CasClientConfiguration.SAML11_TICKET_VALIDATOR_NAME, true) == 0)
                        {
                            ticketValidator = new Saml11TicketValidator();
                        }
```

Then, in the casConfigClient setting in the web.config of the website, add this:

```
ticketValidatorName="ECas"
```

Hope this helps someone out there..